# DNN - differences between Document Library and Digital Asset Management

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

The documentation on DNN sites speak of two default modules namely `Document Library` and `Digital Asset Management`. The two modules seem to be quite similar in functionality i.e. they both provide a mechanism to handle documents. But I haven't found any documentation that explains the different scenarios in which they are to be used. Could anybody explain the different scenarios they are meant to be used in? And which of these modules provides more flexibility in terms of URL management and handling large number of documents of the order of 60,000 to 70,000?

Answer (score 0):

Digital Asset Management is the "File Manager" module in current versions of DNN.

The Document Library module is intended for collections of documents managed outside of the file manager.  It is more suited for presenting a display of documents, descriptions, download links, etc.

For managing large number of modules, you might want to look at the DMX Pro module from Bring2Mind.net.

Answer (score 0):

Or, For managing large number of files, you might want to look at the DNNUserFiles module from Evotiva.com  (Disclaimer: Yes, I'm the author)